# MS Http Server API (< Win 8) and WebSockets

Tags: c++, websocket, httpserver

I try to realize WebSocket protocol at MS Http Server API under win server 2008 (haven't  HTTP_SEND_RESPONSE_FLAG_OPAQUE flag).

```
HTTP_RESPONSE response={0};
const char upgrade_val[]="Websocket";
response.Headers.KnownHeaders[HttpHeaderUpgrade].RawValueLength=strlen(upgrade_val);
response.Headers.KnownHeaders[HttpHeaderUpgrade].pRawValue     =upgrade_val;
const char connection_val[]="Upgrade";
response.Headers.KnownHeaders[HttpHeaderConnection].RawValueLength=strlen(connection_val);
response.Headers.KnownHeaders[HttpHeaderConnection].pRawValue     =connection_val;
HTTP_UNKNOWN_HEADER unknown[1];
response.Headers.UnknownHeaderCount=1;
response.Headers.pUnknownHeaders   =unknown;
const char accept_name[]="Sec-WebSocket-Accept";
unknown[0].NameLength    =_countof(accept_name)-1;
unknown[0].pName         =accept_name;
unknown[0].RawValueLength=HANDSHAKE_KEY_LENGTH;
unknown[0].pRawValue     =base64_key;
response.Version.MajorVersion=1;
response.Version.MinorVersion=1;
response.StatusCode          =HTTP_SWITCHING_PROTOCOLS;
const char reason[]              ="Switching Protocols";
response.ReasonLength        =strlen(reason);
response.pReason             =reason;
HttpSendHttpResponse(iocp,RequestId,HTTP_SEND_RESPONSE_FLAG_MORE_DATA,&raw_response,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

Browser send header (from Fiddler)

```
GET http://server.host/ HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: server.host
Origin: null
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Key: V86c1TFOwWfZqhS42C0arA==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: x-webkit-deflate-frame
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/27.0.1453.94 Safari/537.36
```

server's response (from Fiddler)

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: Websocket
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: 3io2SU7uJIeFlwy0+OFJUDNrA44=
Date: Tue, 28 May 2013 09:27:59 GMT
EndTime: 13:27:59.006
ReceivedBytes: 0
SentBytes: 0
```

and browser shows 1016 error.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` header value is calculated correctly, and assuming your `response` variable is supposed to be named `raw_response` instead, then your response is missing the required `Connection: Upgrade` header despite your code assigning a value for it.

Comment: Yes, Connection: Upgrade is missing, but I wroute it here: response.Headers.KnownHeaders[HttpHeaderConnection].RawValueLength=strlen(connection_val);

Comment: I checked `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` and key is valid but not work.

Comment: Did you see my comment about `raw_response` vs `response`? That tells me that you likely did not copy/paste your real code.

Comment: Can you give me a link to the comment?

Comment: The comment I was referring to is in my answer above: "and assuming your `response` variable is
supposed to be named `raw_response`
instead". The code you provided is declaring a `raw_response` variable, but is filling in headers for a `response` variable instead.

Comment: oh, yes. raw_response === response. Excuseme.

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP_SEND_RESPONSE_FLAG_OPAQUE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Windows 8 and later) is required for WebSockets.

[WebSocket servers on Windows Server](http://nbevans.wordpress.com/2011/12/20/websocket-servers-on-windows-server/) (2011-12-20)

> As it stands right now, Server 2008/R2 boxes cannot host WebSockets.
>   At least, not whilst sharing ports 80 and 443 with IIS web server

[Re: [hybi] WebSocket protocol as it stands](http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/hybi/current/msg04606.html) (2010-11-06)

> we need to tweak http.sys to recognize what is really a non-HTTP
>   request, as an HTTP request